# hdparm standby after X time doesn't work

Tags: server, power-management, external-hdd, hdparm

I have an external WD 8TB hard drive connected to my Dell Wyse 5070 via USB 3.0. Recently I've done a full Ubuntu Server reinstall (on internal SSD). Now when I'm trying to configure everything as I previously had I'm struggling with the external HDD standby time setup.

Previously I configured it somehow so the HDD went standby about 15 minutes after no activity detected.

Right now I'm not able to setup it in a similar manner. For example `sudo hdparm -S 5 /dev/sdb` has no effect after 25 seconds. Hence, the hard drive is active all the time and never goes standby.

`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb` gives

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD80EDAZ-11TA3A0
        Serial Number:      VG00T1YG
        Firmware Revision:  81.00A81
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029)
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 15628053168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes [ Supported: 4096 4160 4224 512 520 528 ]
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     7630885 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     8001563 MBytes (8001 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        Advanced power management level: disabled
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    Media Card Pass-Through
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                unknown 119[6]
           *    unknown 119[7]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
                Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
                DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
                In-order data delivery
           *    Software settings preservation
                unknown 78[7]
                unknown 78[10]
                unknown 78[11]
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
           *    SANITIZE feature set
           *    CRYPTO_SCRAMBLE_EXT command
           *    OVERWRITE_EXT command
           *    reserved 69[3]
           *    reserved 69[4]
           *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
           *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
           *    READ BUFFER DMA command
Security:
        Master password revision code = 48059
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        812min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000cca0bfc05a54
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000cca
        Unique ID       : 0bfc05a54
```

I can see that `Advanced power management level` is `disabled`. Can this be related to the issue?

What's more, `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdb` works as expected. It immediately puts the HDD to sleep.

Any ideas how can I investigate it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully your drive will respond to [the `-B` flag in `hdparm`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/hdparm.8.html), which will allow you to enable/disable the power management feature. From the docs:

```
-B     Get/set  Advanced  Power  Management feature, if the drive supports it. A low value
       means aggressive power management  and  a  high  value  means  better  performance.
       Possible  settings  range  from  values 1 through 127 (which permit spin-down), and
       values 128 through 254 (which do not permit  spin-down).   The  highest  degree  of
       power  management  is attained with a setting of 1, and the highest I/O performance
       with a setting of 254.  A value of 255  tells  hdparm  to  disable  Advanced  Power
       Management  altogether  on the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most
       do).
```

You can check your drive's current value like this:

```
sudo hdparm -B /dev/sdb
```

Given the output from `-I`, I would expect the number to be something like `254`, which does not allow auto spin-down.

With this in mind, let's set a value between `1` and `127`, which Dows allow spin-down:

```
sudo hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdb
```

<sup>**Note:** Based on the documentation, a higher number means better performance. As `127` is the highest one can go while still permitting spin-down, this seems the most logical option.</sup>

If no error is reported, you may be able to set a 5-minute spin-down like this:

```
sudo hdparm -S 60 /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally I was able to understand the difference between hdparm options. Right now my APM_level is set to 127 as you suggested and standby mode is applied after 10 minutes without any issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried the same, but unfortunately, it did not have any effect. Previously the HDD went to sleep as intended, but since I replaced the ext4 file system with bcache and ext4 on top of it, the disk just won't go to sleep by itself. Manual interference still works as expected.

Comment: The use of `bcache` will prevent many of the disk sleep operations from becoming active, as a disk cache needs to be available. If the cache latency is too great (due to re-initialisation processes), then the Linux kernel will begin complaining 